# Internet Explorer 11 is changing value="1_1" to value="1"!! What can I do?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/9ypWX
The issue is this:
I've been working on an application leaning heavily on BootStrap Navbars. In order to pass values to javascript functions, I've added the attribute "value" to many of the li elements.
An example:

---

```
<ul>
   <li value="1_1" onclick="doSomethingTo(this);">Option1</li>
   <li value="1_2" onclick="doSomethingTo(this);">Option2</li>
</ul>
```

Everything is working fine until I try it in Internet Explorer. Then suddenly, internet explorer decides to change the attribute to value="1". It renders at the browser as:

```
<ul>
   <li value="1" onclick="doSomethingTo(this);">Option1</li>
   <li value="1" onclick="doSomethingTo(this);">Option2</li>
</ul>
```

I now have no access to the rest of the value, which is used in the handler function.

Is there anything I can do to IE to make it stop changing attribute values in this case? Is it a known issue?

My workaround now is to change all the attribute names to 'val' instead and change all of my javascript. Not very pleased with this.

Thanks.

Comment: Possibly because `value` on a `li` ins't valid HTML. Try something with `data-`, e.g. `data-value="1_1"`

Comment: Value on li can only be a number ( http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_li_value.asp ) and it is used for ordering the list. Your list is not ordered, why use value?

Answer (score 0):

It's more standard to use `"data-"` as an attribute name prefix when defining nonstandard fields. As @Cristy commented the `"value"` attribute on an `<li>` is intentionally restricted to being a number.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li#attr-value

```
<ul>
   <li data-value="1" onclick="doSomethingTo(this);">Option1</li>
   <li data-value="1" onclick="doSomethingTo(this);">Option2</li>
</ul>
```

...

```
function doSomethingTo(element) {
    console.log(element.getAttribute("data-value"));
}
```

The funny thing is, IE being itself (weird) actually helped find a potential issue!

Comment: "*IE being itself*" Wouldn't that make IE *stricter* to the rules, making it superior in this instance? Wouldn't call it *weird* since the [W3C states](https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/li#HTML_Attributes) the `value` attribute on an `li` (list item) can only be numeric.

Comment: @Marcus - correct. Referring to weirdness here can be compared to the w3 spec (in which case Chrome et al. are weirder) or compared to other browsers.